# Is there a way, ideally using the command line, to convert multiple .csv files to one multi-sheet .xls spreadsheet?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, convert, csv, xls

Is there a way, ideally using the command line, to convert multiple .csv files to one multi-sheet .xls spreadsheet?

If there isn't a cli solution, it'd be good to know if there's an API that works in, ideally, awk or pascal, but, failing that, in pretty-well anything.

Comment: ssconvert, mentioned by Maythux, is a companion command to Gnumeric, which will be installed by default on an Ubuntu Desktop system, but not on a server version.

Comment: Given the fact Excel will load CSV in an `.xls` file you could simply do: `cat *.csv > file.xls`

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150342/csvs-to-multi-sheet-xls-without-excel-installed-powershell)

Comment: ssconvert does the trick, perfectly. What I needed was to have each .csv file in a separate sheet. Using cat doesn't achieve that. ssconvert does.

Comment: @ash csv and xls are different formats, catting a bunch of csvs to a file and renaming it xls wont work at all, since csvs dont support multiple sheets so it would just make one long csv, and also since csv is a plaintext format whereas xls is a binary format

Comment: @chiliNUT - I misread the part where OP wanted multiple CSV files into a single spreadsheet as multiple worksheets.  However, I was only suggesting a way of concatenating multiple CSV files into a single CSV - I realise it's not what's being asked but I do know the difference between a binary and a text file.

Comment: wasnt saying you didnt, just that you may or may not hav e been aware that one was binary and the other wasnt, esp. since most of the recent excel formats are no longer binary either

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the command [ssconvert](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssconvert).

```
ssconvert example.csv example.xls
```

To do it for multiple files you have to make a bash loop over csv files and do the job. Here a hint:

```
for i in *.csv; do ssconvert "$i" "${i%.*}".xls; done
```

**EDIT:**

To convert and merge into one single xls file also you still can use ssconvert.

```
ssconvert --merge-to=output.xls file1.csv file2.csv ....
```

or easily

```
ssconvert --merge-to=output.xls *.csv
```

Comment: It is vital to quote the variables, as `"$i" "${i%.*}".xls`, otherwise any file name containing a space will break the command (and potentially overwrite an unrelated file).